# openlayers 4 supports csv file

Tags: openlayers

I have csv files with coordinates, I was wondering how to read the coordinates directly and render them on the map. It seems openlayers two `OpenLayers.Format.Text` before, but I can not find similar options in ol4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple choices.

- You can use a third party library that convert CSV to GeoJSON and consume the GeoJSON using `ol.format.GeoJSON`. I have [a demo that just do that](https://rawgit.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/tsv/demo-tsv.html).
- You could also convert CSV to JSON with a library like [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) (not tied to D3 nowadays contrary to what the naming could suggest) or another "csv to json" JavaScript library. Then, you will create with more boilerplate code an array of `ol.Feature` populated with `ol.geom.Point` and your fields attributes and provide the array to an `ol.source.Vector` attached to an `ol.layer.Vector`.

Comment: Updated demo link for above: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-extras-demos/master/tsv/demo-tsv.html